# How to know if two or more elements are vertically aligned inside a matrix?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a 5x5 matrix and I need to vertically align some elements acording to some rules. For example: matrix(1,1) = 2 and matrix(5,3) = 5. The numbers 2 and 5 must be aligned in the same column, so a possible solution could be move number 2 to matrix(1,3), or move number 5 to matrix(5,1).

I know how to swap elements inside a matrix but, what is the best way to compare if two elements are in the same column?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column where a 2 is present that way:

```
[~,J2] = find(matrix==2)
```

Same thing for `matrix==5`. Then do the swaps that you need.